# Coroutine StateFlow.collect{} not firing

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I'm seeing some odd behavior.  I have a simple `StateFlow<Boolean>` in my `ViewModel` that is not being collected in the fragment.  Definition:

```
private val _primaryButtonClicked = MutableStateFlow(false)
val primaryButtonClicked: StateFlow<Boolean> = _primaryButtonClicked
```

and here is where I set the value:

```
fun primaryButtonClick() {
    _primaryButtonClicked.value = true
}
```

Here is where I'm collecting it.

```
     repeatOnOwnerLifecycle {
        launch(dispatchProvider.io()) {
            freeSimPurchaseFragmentViewModel.primaryButtonClicked.collect {
                if (it) {
                    autoCompletePlacesStateFlowModel.validateErrors()
                    formValidated = autoCompletePlacesStateFlowModel.validateAddress()
                    if (formValidated) {
                        freeSimPurchaseFragmentViewModel
                            .sumbitForm(autoCompletePlacesStateFlowModel.getStateFlowCopy())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

**repeatOnOwnerLifecycle**:

```
inline fun Fragment.repeatOnOwnerLifecycle(
    state: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED,
    crossinline block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
) {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
     repeatOnLifecycle(state) {
        block()
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The collector never fires.

Comment: How do you observe if `collect()` is firing? Also, are you sure you don't set the state flow to true before starting collecting? State flow sends notifications only when the value changes, so you won't collect anything if set to true multiple times.

Comment: @broot thanks for your answer.  I set a break point.  And yes, I set it to false when I declare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this make sense?

```
val primaryButtonClicked: StateFlow<Boolean> = _primaryButtonClicked.asStateFlow()
```

Also I couldn't understand the inline function part, because under the hood seems you wrote something like this

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
   viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
      launch(dispatchProvider.io()) {
        freeSimPurchaseFragmentViewModel.primaryButtonClicked.collect {
            if (it) {
                autoCompletePlacesStateFlowModel.validateErrors()
                formValidated = autoCompletePlacesStateFlowModel.validateAddress()
                if (formValidated) {
                    freeSimPurchaseFragmentViewModel
                        .sumbitForm(autoCompletePlacesStateFlowModel.getStateFlowCopy())
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Why are you launching one coroutine in another and collect the flow from IO dispatcher? You need to collect the values from the main dispatcher.

Comment: It works.  It was taking out the dispatchers.io()